# Expected result not happens in this regular expression with named groups

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have this template:

```html
Dear @Model["ClientName"] <br><br>

           Thank you for applying to open an account. Your request for a (@Model["AccountType"]/@Model["Platform"]/@Model["Currency"]) has been sent to our Client team. They are currently reviewing your request.<br><br>

Kind regards,<br>
<a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a><br />
+55 00 0000 0000 <br>08:00-18:00 Mon-Fri
```

And would like to replace all `@Model["key"]` with a string value.

I have this regex:

```
const string pattern = @".*(?<model>@Model\[\u0022(?<key>\w+)\u0022\]).*";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

When I check the matches collection I find only 2, ClientName and Currency.

Why is that? I was expecting to find AccountType and Platform too.

Can you help me to identify what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like it's only finding the last match on each line. Have you tried getting rid of the .* before and after? It might be greedily swallowing the rest of the line with the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this match pattern (without the `.*` before and after):

```
const string pattern = @"(?<model>@Model\[\u0022(?<key>\w+)\u0022\])";
```

This will stop the `.*` from greedily swallowing the whole line, and considering it to be a single match.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it :-) Thank you!  (I'll accept your answer in a few minutes, as soon as SO allows me).